# How to set a new FontFamily to my egui app?

Tags: rust, egui, eframe

So i tried the Examples in egui documentation and it works. However
the Examples in the egui documentation, seems to focus on overwriting the existing FontFamily (Proportional,Monospace):

```
let mut fonts = FontDefinitions::default();

// Install my own font (maybe supporting non-latin characters):
fonts.font_data.insert("my_font".to_owned(),
   FontData::from_static(include_bytes!("../../fonts/Ubuntu-Light.ttf"))); // .ttf and .otf supported

// Put my font first (highest priority):
fonts.families.get_mut(&FontFamily::Proportional).unwrap()
    .insert(0, "my_font".to_owned());

// Put my font as last fallback for monospace:
fonts.families.get_mut(&FontFamily::Monospace).unwrap()
    .push("my_font".to_owned());

egui_ctx.set_fonts(fonts);
```

But how to i declare or define a completely new Family in the Enum?

```
pub enum FontFamily {
    Proportional,
    Monospace,
    Name(Arc<str>),
}

pub enum FontFamily {
    Proportional,
    Monospace,
    my_font, <-- How i put the font here as a new FamilyMember? 
    Name(Arc<str>),
}
```

I would like to use my own `my_font` only for specfic labels or fields like in this case:

```
   ui.add(
            egui::TextEdit::singleline(&mut ss)
            .text_color(egui::Color32::LIGHT_RED)
            .font(egui::FontSelection::FontId(FontId::new(
            20.,
            egui::FontFamily::my_font, <--
            ))),
```

Comment: Have you tried `egui::FontFamily::Name ("MYCOOLFONT".into())`?

Comment: In the `ui.add? `Yeah but Error MSG appears  `FontFamily::Name("my_font") is not bound to any fonts`` you have bind it to the enum it seems. But how?

Comment: I'd assume it's the same as for proportional and monospace: `fonts.families.get_mut(&FontFamily::Name ("MYCOOLFONT".into())).unwrap().insert(0, "my_font".to_owned())`

Comment: i changed my question because `MYCOOLFONT` was jsut a placeholder. I would like to add another Member to the `FontFamily` enum. I do not want to substitute `Proportional`or `Monospace`. Or at least i assume you have to add a new font to the enum if you want to access your custom font only on specific labels etc. without substituting existing Members.

Comment: You can't add a a new member to an existing `enum`. The way to add a new font to to `egui` so that you can _"access your custom font only on specific labels etc."_ is to use `FontFamily::Name ("my_font".into())`.

Comment: if i do `FontFamily::Name ("my_font".into())`in a label like -> `ùi.add...` it will tell me my_font is not bound to any font. Yet i inserted it as above in my question.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/emilk/egui/discussions/1420 and https://github.com/amPerl/egui-phosphor/blob/main/examples/multiple_variants.rs